# How to cure Mail of being stuck on one message?

Tags: mail.app

Every time I open Mail, it has the same message selected.  I scroll up three or four screens to the new messages, then close.  Next launch, it's on that same old message again.  It used to select the newest message on open.

The message doesn't appear to be corrupted.  I can read the whole thing, and it's all plain text (via a listserv that doesn't allow attachments or HTML).  I can scroll up and select/read other messages.  Can't find any other malfunction in Mail.  Rebuild Mailbox doesn't help.

Don't want to delete this particular message, just don't want mail to make me look at it on every launch and then scroll & scroll to the new mail.

Reason?  Fix?

Comment: Since the account is IMAP, I deleted it and reinstalled it.  Now Mail selects the newest message on launch.  I hope this is a permanent fix, but I doubt it.  (Issue resolved before but it came back.)

Comment: Didn't last.  It now always selects a message from last Friday when launched.

Comment: Has there been any resolution to this problem as I have it too and deleting a message just sends mail to the next email on the same date. For me that’s October 1, 2017. Nothing has fixed the problem at all so far including rebuild.

Comment: It is still harassing me on the latest updates of IOS and MacOS.  Last time I looked, there was neither help nor encouragement on my bug report.

Answer (score 1):

A corrupted email message can get stuck on your email system, like clogged pipe in your plumbing. In my experience the problem is always one of those joke emails that has been forwarded countless times.

## Web Access To Email

Solution is to **use the Web interface** to your email provider rather than your email client app. In the web browser, find the offending email and delete. If you really need that message - put it in a folder that doesn’t sync if you can.

Then return to your email client. Your pipes should be clear again. You may need to do a Rebuild command to reconstruct your local cache.

Comment: Added info to question.  Not a multi-forward.  Sender to listserv to me.

Comment: @WGroleau So copy what you need from the problem message, then use Web interface to delete. I don't understand why you would rather hang on to a problematic message than fix your email system.

Comment: ?!?!?!  This irritation has been here for weeks, even persisting after a reinstall of the O.S.  But I went to Mail just now to try your advice and the problem has gone away on its own!  The old message is still there, but now is not selected on every launch.   Sigh . . .

Comment: But now it's back, and it is also happening on the iPad, but not the same message as on the MacBook.

Comment: Also, rebuilding the mailboxes doesn't fix it.

Comment: Deleting the "stuck" message is only a temporary fix.  Within a week, it's always stuck again on some message.  On my iPad right now, every time I launch Mail, I have to scroll four or five screens to the new messages.  And often, I would rather keep a message in its proper place in the Mail sequence than try to remember that I put it somewhere else in a futile attempt to workaround a bug.